# "Each others" or "Each other"?

Tags: word-choice

"live far from each others" has 30000 Google results.

"live far from each other" has 60000 Google results.

So which one is right? "Each others" or "Each other"?

Comment: "live far from each others" gives 19 results (with quotation marks) when I google for it.

Comment: "***Each other***" is the correct form, I think the "plural" form you are suggesting is actually "***each other's***".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct form is ***[each other](https://jakubmarian.com/each-others-vs-each-others-in-english/)***, not each others. The following extract may help understand the difference:

> - ***Learners of English (and native speakers alike) sometimes wonder whether they are supposed to write each other’s or each others’*** (or even each others) in phrases like “to hold each other’s hand(s)" .
> - Long story short, ***the correct spelling is the one used in the previous example, i.e. each other’s***. Another example:
>
>   - We didn’t see each other’s face(s). (correct)
>   - We didn’t see each others’ face(s). (wrong)
> - ***This is quite logical***. The possessive form in English is formed by adding ’s at the end of a noun, unless it is a plural noun, in which case we write just an apostrophe, e.g. “these teachers’ books” (not “these teachers’s books”). This rules out each others, as the possessive apostrophe must be there.
> - In the case of “each other”, “other” is in the singular because it follows “each”—you wouldn’t say “each teachers” instead of “each teacher”, would you… By adding the possessive ’s, we get the correct form each other’s.

Another interesting aspect to consider is the usage of plural or singular nouns  following  the expression ***each other's***:

> - What about the noun that follows “each other’s”—are we supposed to use a singular noun (e.g. “each other’s face”) or a plural noun (e.g. “each other’s faces”)? The answer is: Both forms are common. Since “each other’s” basically means “(mutually) the other person’s”, and we wouldn’t say “the other person’s faces” (unless the other person is two-faced), it makes more sense to say “each other’s face”. Nevertheless, the plural form seems to be more common in modern usage, so it can hardly be considered incorrect. In summary:
> - *We saw each other’s faces. (correct, more common)
>     We saw each other’s face. (correct, more logical)
>     This article was based on my guide to the most common mistakes in English, which explains many similar topics. Why don’t you check it out?*

Note also the difference between ***each other vs one onother***:

> - ***We use each other and one another to show that each person in a group of two or more people does something to the others***. There is very little difference between each other and one another and we can normally use them in the same places. Each other is more common than one another.

(jakubmarian.com)